# Why can't I run async code as synchronous

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to understand the async/await mechanism with MVC. Now I do not consider a use case where I would go out of the "normal flow" (using either full sync or full async end-to-end). I just want to make sure to understand the why it doesn't work here.

When "SyncMethod" is called it hangs indefinitely and never returns.

When "AsyncMethod" is called it returns a view quickly without hanging.

When "TaskMethod" is called it returns a view quickly without hanging as well.

I am not exactly sure to understand why when a synchronous method calls an async method it is impossible to return a result.

What am I missing here?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcAsyncAwaitTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Synchronous method running async method as sync
        /// Hangs at Hello().Result, never returns
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ActionResult SyncMethod()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = Hello().Result;
            return View();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Asynchronous method awaiting asynchronous method
        /// Do not hang 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<ActionResult> AsyncMethod()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = await Hello();
            return View("Index");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Synchronous method running a task based method synchronously
        /// Returns a valid result
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ActionResult TaskMethod()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = Hello2().Result;

            return View("index");
        }

        private async Task<string> Hello()
        {
            return await HelloImpl();
        }

        private Task<string> Hello2()
        {
            return Task.Run(() => "Hello world 2");
        }

        private async Task<String> HelloImpl()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => "Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stephen Cleary explains the async/deadlock dilemma here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: What's the point of `Hello()`?  It doesn't do anything.  Just call `HelloImpl` directly.  Also, there's no point in making a method `async` just so you can await one task that you return; just make the method not be `async` and return that task directly.

Comment: @Servy I could make a complex implementation and all, but I prefered to put a very simple example to understand exactly what is the problem here. But if you want a more complex implementation of exactly that look at asp.net identity framework that is used exactly like that.

Comment: @Erick I'm describing how you can simplify your code, not telling you to make it more complex...

Answer (score 8):

The crux of the issue is that `await` will (by default) capture the current "context" and use that to resume the `async` method. In ASP.NET, that "context" is a `SynchronizationContext` that only allows one thread in at a time.

So, when you block the request thread by calling `Result`, you are blocking a thread within that `SynchronizationContext` and thus the `Hello` method cannot resume within that request context.

The reason your `Hello2().Result` works is that it's not actually an `async` method; it's just sticking some work on a thread pool thread, which will complete fine independently of the request thread.

I have a [blog entry](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that goes into the full details.

Answer (score 1):

This is a deadlock. In SyncMethod you are waiting on yourself:

`Hello().Result` waits on your request's thread.

`await HelloImpl()` and the `await Task.Run(...)` inside of `HelloImpl()` both return execution to your request's thread, but can't because the `.Result` is blocking it.